# How to get a black screen and grids drawn?

Tags: python, pygame

I have an issue. Here is my code :

```
import pygame
import tkinter as tk
class cube():
    rows = 20
    w = 500
    def __init__(self, start, dirnx=1, dirny=0, color=(255, 0, 0)):
        pass
class snake(object):
    def __init__(self, color, pos):
        pass
def drawGrid(w, rows, surface):
    b = 255
    sizeBtwn = w // rows
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for l in range(rows):
        x = x + sizeBtwn
        y = y + sizeBtwn
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (b, b, b), (x,0), (x,w))
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (b, b, b), (0,y), (w,y))
def redrawWindow(surface):
    global rows, width
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    drawGrid(width, rows, surface)
    pygame.display.update()
def main():
    global width, rows
    width = 1280
    height = 720
    rows = 40
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    s = snake((255, 0, 0), (10, 10))
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while run:
        clock.tick(30)
        redrawWindow(win)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I launch I have nothing. I have a grey window. But I should have a black window with grids... Why does nothing appear ?

Thank you to help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle the events, by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
This functions do not handle the internal events, too. This is necessary to keep the system responding and for updating the display.

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while run:

        # handle events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        clock.tick(30)
        redrawWindow(win)
```

Comment: pygame doesn't quit instantly. It's just my window is grey and only grey.

Comment: It's weird...not for me.

Comment: Thank you ! I added : 

`for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False` And now it's working...but why ?

Comment: @MrRex What was the issue?

Comment: I don't understand why it's working after writing this : 

`for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False `

Comment: These lines are juste to close pygame window, no ?

Comment: @MrRex That is exactly  what I've written and explained in my answer. It is because now the (internal) events are handled by `pygame.event.get()`.